# Persist ifconfig lo multicast across reboots on Linux RHEL 6

Tags: linux, networking, localhost

Is there a way to persist the following command across reboots on Linux  RHEL 6 (other than perhaps creating an init.d script):

```
ifconfig lo multicast
```

I have an application that requires multicast on 127.0.0.1, and I was wondering whether there's something in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts that can help persist the ifconfig lo multicast across reboots.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the /etc/rc.local suggestion; it would work, and it's technically not an init.d script, so in my humble opinion, the -1 is a bit unfair. However, I'd like to avoid that route if possible in order to improve the maintenance of the file.

After some digging around, I couldn't find any files in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ that could help; however, I did find a potential solution; after tracing the ifup scripts, there's a hook to invoke an ifup-${DEVICE} file; since that doesn't exist for lo, I've created an ifup-lo file with 755 permissions as follows:

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-lo

```
# ifconfig is deprecated; use ip link instead...
/sbin/ip link set lo multicast on
/sbin/ip link set lo up
```

This will be invoked by the os when ifup lo is called, allowing any custom hooks to be added.

Any better solutions are appreciated.

The ideal solution would be for Redhat to add a MULTICAST=on  or MULTICAST=off variable in the /etc/ifcfg-lo , but since that's not currently in place, ifup-lo will do for now...

Answer (score 0):

append `ifconfig lo multicast` to the end of /etc/rc.local

Comment: Although not an ideal solution, I agree with @Leo that this did not seem to deserve a -1.  I may fall back to this if I don't get the other solutions working.